# Custom directories through php

Tags: php, routes

Hey i was wondering how people made websites that are dynamic in the sense that they can use URL's like /user/kappa in their website without having the actual folder in the files.

I am not quite sure how they do this but i have been looking around for a while and couldn't find an example so i thought i may ask here!

`https://domain.tld/user/kappa`

like how it says /user/kappa but doesn't make the folders physically
is there a way i can do this using PHP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: apache `mod_rewrite`

Comment: You can use htaccess and redirections if you are using apache server

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use `mod_rewrite`.

You can add a few lines to your .htaccess file to set it up. What it is doing is taking a PHP file with a set of variables and re-writing the URI based on rules you set out. For example, you may have one index.php file that handles all your content with different variables. ie:

```
example.com/index.php?page=news&id=34
```

You could use mod rewrite to change this to

```
example.com/news/title.html
```

As an example this is some of the code the CMS Joomla uses for its URLs. I also found this page which goes over some basic examples. http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/1/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```